# Retrieving history for deleted data

Tags: mysql, query-cache

I see a deleted query fired in the mysqld query-cache:

```
delete from artist_table where id = 463960;
```

I need to know the data associated with id `463960` (which no longer exists) and I don't have any backups nor I have logging enabled. Does mysql store the data in some archival/historical table after the data is deleted? Is there any way I can retrieve it?

Comment: You should find the record in your query log if you have it enabled. (You should be able to find the insert for that row) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: @Octopus-Paul No, the logging is not enabled.

Comment: Do you have a backup of that table/database somewhere? If your answer is yes, then load your backup on a different machine, search by that id and get your data from there. If not, I don't know what to do.

Comment: You may check my.ini. if log-bin is open. you may have chance to recover. if not, i have no idea what to do.